# How to execute multiple training operation on the same batch using tf.data dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to implement the code available [here](https://github.com/Naresh1318/Adversarial_Autoencoder/blob/master/adversarial_autoencoder.py) using a tf.data dataset and iterator (adversarial autoencoder).

My question is how to use the same batch for multiple training ops?

I need to perform three different training operations on the same batch, however, if I use the tf.data iterator, it does not work on the same batch but on consecutive ones.

Comment: Doesn't using `sess.run([autoencoder_optimizer,discriminatior_optimizer,generator_optimizer],feed_dict=...)` work?

Comment: @Siladittya according to the documentation there is no guarantee that they will be sequential.

Comment: @itzikBenShabat If the operations depend upon each other then they will execute in that order. If they are not dependent, how do you actually care ?

Comment: @Ujjwal the operation themselves are independent of each other but the order of updating the model parameter matters (In the case of Adversarial autoencoders).

Comment: In such cases, just use `tf.control_dependencies()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose `data = db_iter.get_next()`, where `db_iter` is the iterator you are using from `tf.data`.

I suppose you are traning the `3` ops in `3` different `sess.run` statements. In that case they will all use `3` different batches as `data` will be evaluated `3` times.

The fact is that, if the input to each of the three `training ops` are provided from `data` as defined above, and run within each `sess.run`, they will all use the same batch.